# When I need to remove `super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)` from `form-valid`?

Tags: python, django

> No URL to redirect to.  Either provide a url or define a
>   get_absolute_url method on the Model.

I have the following class wherein I explicitly defined a redirect method which should prevent that above error.

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ('message',)
    template_name = 'board/edit_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_pk'
    context_object_name = 'post'


    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super().get_queryset()
        # ! queryset.objects.filter
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.updated_by = self.request.user 
        post.updated_at = timezone.now() 
        post.save()
        super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)

        return redirect('board:view_topic', pk=post.topic.board.pk, topic_pk=post.topic.pk)
```

I then deleted `super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)` from here and everything worked fine. Don't know why it should be like this?

Similar to below function, when I always call `form_valid` I always add `super().form_valid()` why I have to delete it above there to make it work.

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

i hope you help me thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)`, the update view [saves the form and tries to redirect to the view's success URL](https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/2.2/django.views.generic.edit/UpdateView/#form_valid).

In this case, Django doesn't know which URL to redirect to. As the error messages suggests, you can fix the problem by setting `success_url` or `get_success_url` on the view, or adding a `get_absolute_url` method to the model.

However, since you are already saving the object and returning a redirect response, calling `super(PostUpdateView, self).form_valid(form)` is just repeating the code you have already written. It is fine to remove it.

Comment: def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse('board:view_topic',
                       args=(post.topic.board.pk, post.topic.pk, ))

Comment: You don't have access to `post` in `get_success_url`, so you would have to use `self.object` instead.

Comment: Thank you so much brother specially for that useful link that can solve a lot of future headaches